# What is wrong in my request body to the Amazon SES Api?

Tags: json, http, salesforce, amazon-sesv2

I am a Salesforce developer, and recently I've been trying to integrate the AWS SES Api into my project. I have run into many issues along the way ([you can follow here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414507/calling-aws-simple-email-service-from-apex/414597#414597))

I have successfully managed to post to AWS SES and get emails sent however, when I try to send a request using the [Templated email method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/API_SendEmail.html#SES-SendEmail-request-EmailTags) I run into an issue.

JSON body

```json
{
    "Content": {
        "Template": {
            "TemplateData": "{\"unsubscribe\":\"test\"}",
            "TemplateName": "Welcome_Email"
        }
    },
    "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": [
            "<redacted email address>"
        ]
    },
    "FromEmailAddress": "<redacted email address>",
    "ReplyToAddresses": [
        "<redacted email address>"
    ]
}
```

When I send the request using this Body it responds with a Status 400 with a body of `{"Message":null}`

When I send an Email using the Simple method, it's successful and send the email

```json
{
    "Content": {
        "Simple": {
            "Body": {
                "Html": {
                    "Charset": "UTF-8",
                    "Data": "Test"
                }
            },
            "Subject": {
                "Charset": "UTF-8",
                "Data": "Test"
            }
        }
    },
    "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": [
            "<redacted email address>"
        ]
    },
    "FromEmailAddress": "<redacted email address>",
    "ReplyToAddresses": [
        "<redacted email address>"
    ]
}
```

Right now I am just going to create the html data and use the simple method but I would like to be able to use templates in the future.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Figured out the formatting of my JSON was wrong here

Incorrect:

```
"TemplateData": "{\"unsubscribe\":\"test\"}"
```

Correct:

```
"TemplateData": "{unsubscribe:test}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).